# How to select a particular field value from a list of field names in a combo list?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am new to VBA Access programming and was hoping that some of you experts can help me with a problem.

**Scenario:**

I have a datasheet in Access that displays the values from a corresponding table. My table has 3 columns A,B and C. My datasheet will have 5 columns - A,B,C,Result and `ListBoxValue`.

Essentially my `ListBoxValue` column comprises of a `listbox` with the names of the table columns(ie. A, B and C). This `listbox` is created for each row.

**Problem:**

What I am trying to achieve is this:

When I select one of the columns from the `listbox`, the value of the Result should reflect the value corresponding to the column selected in the list.

Here's an example:

Supposing my datasheet looks like this:

```
A | B | C | Result | ListBoxValue

1 | 2 | 3 | blank | List with values(A,B,C)

10 | 20 | 30 | blank | List with values(A,B,C)
```

For row 1: If I select A from the list, result should also be updated to 1.
If I select B from the list, result field should be updated to 2 etc,etc

I hope you get my problem. I have looked into `Dlookup` but I don't know how to construct it for my datasheet since I don't have any primary keys defined or record identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

You need a datasheet **form** for this, I assume it has the column "ListBoxValue", which is a Combobox with `RowSourceType = "Value List"` and `RowSource = "A";"B";"C"`.

Now you go into Design view of the form, and set an `AfterUpdate` event procedure for the Combobox:

```
Private Sub ListBoxValue_AfterUpdate()

    Me!Result = Me(Me!ListBoxValue.Value)

End Sub
```

So if you e.g. pick the value "A", this will run `Me!Result = Me("A")` which will copy the value of column "A" to "Result".